# Proof of (P → Q) from ¬P?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to figure out how to prove P → Q from just ¬P. I can deduce it using informal logic. Since the only way a conditional is False is in the case of T → F, if P is False, P → Q must always be true.

But I can't seem to prove it formally using a combination of these:(negation/conjunction/disjunction/conditional - introduction/elimination).

Ultimately I want to use this to prove ¬(P → Q) → P by negation elimination.

Comment: Contrapositive you mean?

Comment: I could not prove it, it seems to me like taking a hyptothesis for granted.

Comment: I'm trying to prove P from assumptions: ¬P, ¬(P → Q), (P → Q) and negation elimination. But I don't know how to get to (P → Q).

Comment: @user1869558 I want to recommend this text about similar problems: http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Logic-Text-Elementary-Symbolic/dp/0195080297

Comment: @user1869558 What do you mean by "Prove $P$ from assumptions: $\neg P$, ..."?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m going to answer on the basis of the derivational system suggested by the terminology that you’re using for your rules. What I’m doing may not be quite like what you’ve been taught, but I hope that it’s at least close.

You have $\neg P$ as hypothesis, and from that you want to derive $P\to Q$. To get $P\to Q$ by conditional introduction, you’ll need to start by taking $P$ as an assumption:

$$\begin{align*}
&1.\quad \neg P\tag{Premise}\\
&2.\quad|\,P\tag{Assumption}
\end{align*}$$

We want to end up concluding $Q$ within the scope of the assumption, since conditional introduction will then give us $P\to Q$. Introduce a second assumption layer:

$$\begin{align*}
&1.\quad \neg P\tag{Premise}\\
&2.\quad|\,P\tag{Assumption}\\
&3.\quad||\,\neg Q\tag{Assumption}\\
&4.\quad||\,P\\
&5.\quad||\,\neg P\\
&6.\quad||\,\bot\\
&7.\quad|\,\neg\neg Q\\
\end{align*}$$

Here $\bot$ is a standard symbol for a contradiction, and deriving the contradiction from the assumption $\neg Q$ gives me $\neg\neg Q$ by negation introduction, thereby discharging the inner assumption; I’ll leave the other justifications so far to you.

Now you need some steps deriving $Q$ from $\neg\neg Q$; I’ll leave them to you. (You may have done or seen this derivation already.) Once those are in place, you can discharge the outer assumption by conditional introduction to get $P\to Q$.

Comment: I like this, and it answers the nonintuitive side of what is being asked really well: supposing you can discharge an assumption (in favor of its negation) once a contradiction is reached, the "trivial truths" arise by assuming an arbitrary conclusion once you have already secretly-derived a contradiction but not yet asserted it -- then negating that arbitrary conclusion gives you a trivial truth.

Answer (score 13):

The details of the  proof will depend on the proof system you want to use.

- Clue 1: P → Q is classically equivalent to $ (\neg P \vee Q)$
- Clue 2: $ (\neg P \vee Q)$ is a dilution of $\neg P$

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to use a truth table, which is just as rigorous if not as appealing. If you can't though then I'd consider the following.

$$\neg P \to Q \lor \neg P$$

and then using a simple variation of what is considered a definition by some texts $$Q \lor \neg P \iff \neg(\neg P)\to Q$$ implies what you want.

Comment: What if P is false?

Comment: We're given that P is false? That's the starting point of the question

Comment: But how can you know P is distinct from Q?

Comment: @K.Power We are given $\neg P$, this is not the same as saying $P$ is false.

Comment: If you are a vampire then it's the same as a ghost because you don't exist either way.

Comment: @Programmer400 What is the problem if $P$ is false?

Comment: @AdamFrancey Ok yeah that's true, we're not given the actual truth values just $\neg P$, but the implication still holds regardless.

Comment: @MarcoDisce Please comment my attempt to answer. It is not true (¬) that we live on the moon (P) so that we need oxygen tanks (P → Q) and therefore ¬(P → Q). This does not imply that we live on the moon. I think that the statement is false: "¬(P → Q) → P"

Comment: "which is just as rigorous" -- provided that you've already proved the theorem that every tautology is provable in propositional calculus. The proof of that theorem is potentially a moment at which all this business about manipulating axioms using rules of procedure goes out the window so far as propositional calculus is concerned, and we just throw truth tables at anything with a manageable number of atoms ;-)

Comment: @Programmer400 It's true. Consider "if we live on the moon, we need to carry oxygen tanks". The only way this can be false is if we live on the moon and don't need to carry oxygen tanks. So if we're given both "We don't need to carry oxygen tanks" and "If we live on the moon, we do need oxygen tanks", we can conclude that we don't live on the moon. If we did, we'd need oxygen tanks, which we don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: but we aren't given "If we live on the moon, we do need oxygen tanks", we're given "it is not the case that if we live on the moon, we do need oxygen tank". The reason this confuses people is that we don't all have a solid intuition about what it means for an implication to be false. ¬(P → Q) → P is indeed true, but it surprises people that the only way an implication can be false is if its antecedent is true. Of course it's just the contrapositive of the better-known statement that if the antecedent is false then the implication is true (regardless of Q).

Comment: To put it another way, it surprises people that "if we live on the moon then we're unicorns" is only false if we actually live on the moon. In everyday language this similar-looking but significantly different statement *is* false despite us living on earth: "if we lived on the moon then we would be unicorns". "No we wouldn't be unicorns", we quite reasonably think, "we'd be humans on the moon". But P → Q doesn't involve that kind of hypothetical speculation.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, you stated something other than logical implication because you made it conditional and you implied a causal link.  What you want is "if we live on the moon, we are unicorns". That keeps everything in the present tense unconditional ("live", "are") and does not imply causality (no "then"). Now someone cannot reasonably think "we would be humans on the moon" because the tense and conditionality are wrong. (The statement isn't about what we would be, but about what we are.)  And they certainly can't reasonably think we are humans on the moon because we aren't.